# getting BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) when trying to do something when battery is at a defined level

Tags: java, android, android-studio, batterymanager

I am trying to change the text of TextView when the battery is at a defined level, but when that happened I got an error instead, the error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } in famium.fokus.fhg.de.monitoringthebatterylevelandchargingstate.MainActivity$1@4139cca8
```

and here my code, I commented before the lines taht causes the error.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /*
            BatteryManager
                The BatteryManager class contains strings and constants used for values in the
                ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED Intent, and provides a method for querying battery
                and charging properties.
        */
        /*
            public static final String EXTRA_SCALE
                Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: integer containing the maximum battery level.
                Constant Value: "scale"
        */
        // Get the battery scale
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE,-1);
        // Display the battery scale in TextView
        mTextViewInfo.setText("Battery Scale : " + scale);

        /*
            public static final String EXTRA_LEVEL
                Extra for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: integer field containing the current battery
                level, from 0 to EXTRA_SCALE.

                Constant Value: "level"
        */
        // get the battery level
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
        // Display the battery level in TextView
        mTextViewInfo.setText(mTextViewInfo.getText() + "\nBattery Level : " + level);

        // Calculate the battery charged percentage
        float percentage = level/ (float) scale;
        // Update the progress bar to display current battery charged percentage
        mProgressStatus = (int)((percentage)*100);

        // Show the battery charged percentage text inside progress bar
        mTextViewPercentage.setText("" + mProgressStatus + "%");

        // Show the battery charged percentage in TextView
        mTextViewInfo.setText(mTextViewInfo.getText() +
                "\nPercentage : "+ mProgressStatus + "%");

        // Display the battery charged percentage in progress bar
        mProgressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
            Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

            int level1 = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale1 = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
            int percent = (level1*100)/scale1;
 // here the lines that causes the error
            if (percent >= 97) {
                _textView2.setText(percent);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I tried to follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910024/9308420 but I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Just to point out, while this likely wont fix your problem, you will run into another after this one is fixed. You cannot update anything on the UI without being in a UI thread. Be default, when this is called, you will not be in the UI thread anymore (because broadcast receivers do not wait in the UI thread to receive their broadcast, that would cause a "This application has stopped running" error). You would need to handle that in some manner to update the TextView.

Comment: Additionally, I think we would need to see where you have this implemented (where you set the Broadcast Receiver). Finally, post your entire logcat error please. The error you have has nothing to do with setting a textview with an integer. I imagine the error is occurring a few lines before when you are trying to get the extras out of the intent you receive.

Sorry for multiple comments, but this is not an answer and was too long to be one comment

Comment: I figured it out after reading this post  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23791368/9308420  I posted the answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after reading this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23791368/9308420

so, instead of

```
_textView2.setText(percent);
```

Changed to

```
_textView2.setText("" + percent);
```